# Extract locations of a string and associate information with this parts

Tags: java, regex, string, data-structures

I have a string that inside has some kind of metadata that "describe" parts of the string.
Example:

```
This is an {TypeAStart}arbitrary long{TypeAEnd} text which has {TypeBStart}various{TypeBEnd} usages
```

What I want is to get the indexes of the strings that are contained inside these tags.
My first thought was something like:

```
String[] tags = [ "{TypeA", "{TypeB", etc ];  
for(String tag:tags)  {  
   int start = mainString.indexOf(tag + "Start");  
   if(start != -1) {  
      int end = mainString.indexOf(tag + "End}", start);  
      // store somewhere start,end  
   } 
}
```

But I think this approach is hacky and error prone. How can I do this efficiently with regexes?

**UPDATE:**
I have this string as I mentioned and these metadata are marks where styling is to be applied.
So in the example string above, I would need somehow to have a separate datastructure that would "describe" that `TypeA` is applicable for the string from `"arbitrary long"` which is from position 23-36.

My main target is to have the original string stripped of the tags and in another data structure the indexes and styles.

Comment: Why do you want indexes? What do you actually want to do (once you have the indexes)?

Comment: @Bohemian:These tags are metadata about the string and I need to know which part of the string are these applicable *after* the tags are stripped

Comment: @Jim, check my latest edit, if that helps..

Comment: @Bohemian:Does my comment answer your question?

Comment: @jim not really. Knowing "which part of the string" is in itself useless information. Just tell us, ultimately, what it is you're trying to achieve *overall*.

Comment: @Bohemian:I did not want to complicate the post with too many questions. Please see update.

Comment: @Jim yes, there is quite a bit "overall". Fair enough to leave this question as it is (ie narrow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this work. However it supposes that tags are correctly paired, otherwise will return full content including incorrectly embedded tag.

```
pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{((\\w+)Start)\\}(.*?)\\{(\\2End)\\}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matches(input);

while (matcher.find()) {
    // matcher.start(1) matcher.end(1) matcher.group(1) return index of start of opening tag, its end and content
    // similarly for end tag - start(4) etc.
    // similarly for tag content - start(3) etc.
    // group(2) returns just the tag name
    String result = matcher.group(3);
    // do something with result
}
```

Comment: I don't want the actual string only. I need the indexes of the tags also

Comment: You can get them by invoking matcher methods: group(1), group(4) or start/end (1 or 4)

Comment: I checked this. It does not work in case of nested tags. E.g. {TypeAStart} blabla {TypeBStart} some other blabla {TypeBEnd} other blabla {TypeAEnd}

Comment: In that case you would need to implement stack and process manually tags one by one. Definitely not possible with regular expressions. You'd just search for similar expression with (Start|End) and according to this decide whether to push or pop from the stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the start and end of the pattern match using `m.start()` and `m.end()`.

Live demo: http://ideone.com/jp1Ptn

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String str = "This is an {TypeAStart}arbitrary long{TypeAEnd} text which has {TypeBStart}various{TypeBEnd} usages";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{(.*?)\\}");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

        while(m.find())
        {
            System.out.print(m.group(1));
            System.out.print(" - ");
            System.out.println(m.start() + " : " + m.end());
        }

    }
}
```

Using the following regex `Pattern.compile("\\{(.*?)\\}");` I am specifying the starting and ending delimiters that you have, such as `{` and `}`. `m.group(1)` simply assimilates all the findings.

Results:

```
TypeAStart - 11 : 23
TypeAEnd   - 37 : 47
TypeBStart - 63 : 75
TypeBEnd   - 82 : 92
```

Comment: But I dont want the tags. I want the indexes that mark the start/end of the string

Comment: `TypeAStart - 11 : 23` These are the position of the tags in the string. I need the position where the first letter of the **contained** string starts and where it ends and which tag marked it. In this case it would be (24-36)

Comment: Okay, how would it be 24-36 though?

Comment: For example, I am interested in the `arbitrary long` part and that it is marked by the `TypeA` tags.

Comment: Then why aren't you simply looking for text between `}` and `{` ?