# Find position of sections within a string marked by special markers

Tags: java, string, algorithm, oop, data-structures

I have a string to process that parts of it are "marked" with custom tags to indicate an area of the string that is "different" from the rest.

Example:
`This is an {TypeAStart}arbitrary long{TypeAEnd} text`

The `arbitrary long` part is an area within the string that is of interest.
I wanted a good way to get the start and end index of this part of the string and with regex I can do that ([regex question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33377597/extract-locations-of-a-string-and-associate-information-with-this-parts/33377797?noredirect=1#comment54625773_33377797))
The problems with using such type of approach are:
1) I can not easily generalize it
2) My main target is to end up with the string `This is an arbitrary long text` and have another data structure that describes which marker was applied and where in the **final** string.
I can not see any straightforward way to do this via regular expressions.

What I would like to achieve is to have e.g. an array of these custom markers as pairs and process the string to find all these substrings.
Example input:

```
This is an {TypeAStart}arbitrary long {SomeOtherStart} very very very {SomeOtherEnd} long long{TypeAEnd} text
```

Known markers:
[TypeAStart, TypeAEnd], [SomeOtherStart, SomeOtherEnd] etc

Output:

- This is an arbitrary long very very very long long text
- TypeA [11, 50] , SomeOther [26, 40]

How can I implement this?

Comment: So you're basically duplicating XML syntax, just with `{somethingEnd}` instead of `</something>`? If that's the case then I'm afraind my take would be to regex-replace them to XML tags then run the result through XML parser :)

Comment: @JiriTousek:It is not that advanced or complex really. The text is small and the markers are few and the nesting is not frequent and only 2-3 markers. I could hardcode everything but coding like that would make the code too convoluted and unmaintable. Basically a mess which I am trying to avoid

Comment: @JiiTousek:Also how would the XML parser help? I want the indexes not the actual text

Comment: I can imagine using SAX parser then and catching the events: text - add to output StringBuilder, tag start - remember it's posiiton based on StringBuilder actual size, tag end - get the position, pair with tag start and store the result.

Comment: You can do it similar way with your original format too, but you'd need to parse it yourself. Not too hard if the input is short and there's no `{`'s and `}`'s allowed in the text apart from markers. Basically all you need is an output StringBuilder and a stack of open tags.

Answer (score 0):

I have an open source project that can help with that:

http://mtimmerm.github.io/dfalex/

Lets say you have an Enum Marker with values like TYPEASTART and TYPEAEND, and lets say the values implement a method String text() that gets the string to search for.

You can add patterns for your markers to a DfaBuilder, which will give you a DFA that you can use to find the markers in strings, like this:

```
DfaBuilder<Marker> builder = new DfaBuilder<>();
for (Marker val : Marker.values())
{
    builder.addPattern(Pattern.match(val.text()), val);
}
DfaState<Marker> START_STATE = builder.build();
```

Then you can use this with a StringMatcher to find your patterns:

```
StringMatcher matcher = new StringMatcher(someString);
Marker found;
while((found = matcher.findNext(START_STATE))!=null)
{
    //found is the kind of marker we found
    //this is the start position in the string
    int startPos = matcher.getLastMatchStart();
    //this is the end position in the string
    int endPos = matcher.getLastMatchEnd();
}
```

If you remember the positions of the start markers, you can easily extract the strings between markers when you find the matching end markers.

To get the string between without markers, open a StringBuilder and fill it with the stuff between markers until you get to the end